# REST API response of Array Data Provider

Tags: rest, api, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am developing api to get all users

URL is

```
v1/users?fields=id,full_name
```

Here is the code

```
 public function actionIndex() {
    $provider =  new ArrayDataProvider([
     'allModels' => User::find()->all(),
     'sort' => [
         'attributes' => ['id'],
     ],
     'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
        ],
    ]);

    return $provider;
}
```

OUT put is

```
 [
{
    "id": 4,
    "full_name": "Shahid admin"
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "full_name": "First client"
}
]
```

But when i change the out put in another format:

```
return (new ApiResponse)->success(['user' => $provider], ApiResponse::success);
```

then output is changed ie give me whole object of user model and pagination not working

```
{
    "name": "Success",
    "message": "Success",
    "code": 200,
    "status": "",
    "type": "Response",
    "models": {
        "user": {
            "key": null,
            "allModels": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "full_name": "First client",
                    "profile_image_id": null,
                    "profile_image": null,
                    "isverify": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "full_name": "Eng instrcutor",
                    "profile_image_id": null,
                    "profile_image": null,
                    "isverify": 1
                },
```

Comment: What is `ApiResponse`?

Comment: yes it will return data in above format because you are create a object ApiResponse with your data, so it will return ApiResponse object format